# Configure Jboss EAP 6.1 interface

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

I would like to configure JBoss in standalone mode, and access my application using either localhost (http://localhost:8084/MyApp) or the ip of my machine (http://ip:8084/MyApp) ?
I could configure a interface to connect using either localhost or the ip but not both.
Here is my configuration :

```
<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="my-interface">
            <inet-address value="IP"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add the tag `any-address` instead of `inet-address` in the public interface

Eg:

```
<interfaces>
    ...

    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>

    ...
</interfaces>
```

See also: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Interfaces+and+ports

Comment: Isn't this the same as binding to 0.0.0.0; which is not recommended for security reasons? What if I want to bind only to a specific IP and localhost but no others... is it possible?

Comment: @FGreg you can bind to 0.0.0.0 and restrict access with firewall rules